# Concat values from parents and childs to sort items

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have a table pointing to itself:

```
ID, varchar
PARENTID, varchar
```

For top level items, PARENTID is an empty string.
For all children, PARENTID points to an ID.

There is another table with some sort options:

```
ITEMID, varchar
SORT, varchar
```

ITEMID corresponds to the ID in the other table.
SORT is some sort value, ranging from '0001' to '9999'.

I need to do some sorting based on these critera:

- A parent should always have its children directly beneath it
- Items on the same level should just be sorted based on their respective SORTs

So my idea was to concat the SORT values for a child all the way to its parent like so:
CHILDSORT = GRANDPARENTSORT_PARENTSORT_SORT

Starting from a child, how do I bubble up all the way to its ancestor (the one without a parent) while concatting their sorts?

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: Provide an initial script and desired output, please

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) to get a derived table, and include columns for anything you might want to sort by so that you can ORDER BY those columns in the outer query.